# File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I keep getting this error everytime i try to upload an image using laravel and am sure its a permissions problem but i don't know how to go about it
upload code

```
$destinationPath ='uploads';
    $extension = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();//getting image extension
    $photoName = (rand() * time()).'.'.$extension;//renaming image
    Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $photoName);//uploading file to serve
```

error

```
unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0
```

in my app the /storage directory has these permissions

```
drwxrwxrwx  5 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 25 10:04 storage
```

and the tmp directory has these permissions

```
drwxrwxrwx   3 root root  4096 Jul 13 13:48 tmp
```

Any suggestions on how i could solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $photoName = (rand() * time()).'.'.$extension;
```

try using re-writing the line of code

```
$temp_file_name= rand()*time();
$photoName= $temp_file_name.'.'.$extension;
```

Comment: check whether you can able to create file using static name
Input::file('photo')->move("/etc/temp/","filename.png");

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
$destinationPath = '/uploads';
.....
.....
Input::file('photo')->move(public_path().$destinationPath, $photoName);
```